# Caroufredsel back button not showing previous items; shows random items

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I'm working on an implementation of caroufredsel, and all is working great except the back button.

I show 3 items, then scroll.  When you click the forward button, it scrolls forward 3 items.  When you click the back button, only one item shows, and it is not necessarily the previous item in the list.

Here's the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j(function() {

                //  Variable number of visible items with variable sizes
                $j('#foo3').carouFredSel({
                    width:'100%',
                    height: 'auto',
                    prev : {
                          button : "#prev3",
                          key : "left"
                       },
                    next : { 
                          button : "#next3",
                          key : "right"
                       },
                    auto: true,
                    items: '3',
                    scroll: {
                        duration:1000,
                        items: 3,
                        pauseOnHover: true
                    }       
                });
            });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In the scroll object you have `items: '3'` instead of `items: 1`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(function() {

            //  Variable number of visible items with variable sizes
            $j('#foo3').carouFredSel({
                width:'100%',
                height: 'auto',
                prev : {
                      button : "#prev3",
                      key : "left"
                   },
                next : { 
                      button : "#next3",
                      key : "right"
                   },
                auto: true,
                items: '3',
                scroll: {
                    duration:1000,
                    items: 1,
                    pauseOnHover: true
                }       
            });
        });
```